# What video game is being played in Spiderhead (2022)?

Tags: game-identification

In the 2022 film *[Spiderhead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiderhead)*, one of the main characters, Jeff (played by Miles Teller) is playing what appears to be an 80s arcade game. The player character and the enemies are riding large birds. Its "game over" message is "Thy game is over."

Animated GIF and screencaps of the game:

[image: [animated gif of the described video game]][image: screencap of the game][image: screencap of the game]

##### What video game is being played in *Spiderhead*?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It appears to be [Joust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joust_(video_game)), a 1982 arcade game developed by Williams Electronics and Atari, in which the player controls a yellow knight riding a flying ostrich.

[image]

Comment: I remember playing this as part of a bundle of games in [_Williams Arcade's Greatest Hits_](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Williams_Arcade%27s_Greatest_Hits) for the Sega Saturn

Comment: This makes me want to re-read the book *Ready Player One*

Comment: OT, I love how old arcades were so random. "Here is John the yellow knight riding a space ostrich in space, jumping on space birds that shoot yellow energy balls. No more lore, take it or leave it."

Comment: This is a great game.

Comment: @Neinstein the yellow things are eggs, not shots. They hatch into ostrich knights unless the player picks them up within a few seconds.

Comment: @toolforger sure, space birds that shoots ostrich eggs. Now it definitely makes more sense.

Comment: @pinckerman the eggs drop from dead enemy ostrich riders. So yeah is does make total sense, sure :-D

Comment: @pinckerman They're actually *human* eggs. Once they hatch into space ostrich knights, they call for their ostrich steed to come pick them up. Also, you get attacked by pterodactyls if you take too long. 

Comment: FWIW, Joust (1982) was [the inspiration for Mario Bros.](https://www.denofgeek.com/games/mario-bros-nintendo-arcade/) (1983): “Miyamoto was, he later admitted, inspired by a hit arcade game called Joust, designed by John Newcomer and released by Williams in 1982. Unlike the Donkey Kong games, Joust could be played simultaneously by two players, and saw them flying around a static screen and knocking down enemy knights.”

Comment: Never mind ostriches are famously *flightless* birds, like, the one basic fact everybody knows about ostriches.  But sure.  Still makes more sense than basically anything in the Mario universe it inspired.  Seriously, think about everything in every Mario game.  If you tried to describe it to someone who'd somehow never heard of the franchise, they'd think you were a crazy person.